# Proving a Basis in a Field of Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $B=(f_0,...,f_n)$ be a sequence of polynomials in $\mathbb{F}[t]_n$ of degrees $0,...,n$, respectively.

(i) Prove that $B$ is a basis of $\mathbb{F}[t]_n$.

(ii) For $f\in\mathbb{F}[t]_n$, how to calculate $[f]_B$ if $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$, and there is $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_i=(t-a)^i$?

I know how to prove a basis for an explicit family of vectors (by showing that they are maximal linearly independent).

For instance, I would take $0=c_1(a_1,a_2)+c_2(b_1,b_2)$, and show $c_1=c_2=0$. I am having trouble applying the concept to this general form, however.

Comment: What is $F[t]_n$?

Comment: I guess, the vector space of polynomials of degree $\le n$.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

Translate the conditions by writing $f_i=a_{i0}+a_{i1}t+a_{i2}t^2+\dots$ where $a_{ij}=0$ if $j>i$ and $a_{ii}\ne 0$.

(i) Prove that $1$ can be expressed by $f_0$, $\ t$ can be expressed by $f_0$ and $f_1$, and in general $t^k$ can be expressed by $f_0,\dots,f_k$, for all $k\le n$.

(ii) Call $s:=t-a$ and take the coefficients of $g(t):=f(t+a)$.

Comment: For part (i), how does this help show that it is maximal linearly independent? If $f_i$ equals 0, then all of the $a_i$ values must be 0 as well, right?

Comment: Yes, $f_i$ is assumed to have degree $i$, so $a_{ii}\ne 0$. It shows that it is a *generating system*.

Comment: This is an inductive process, but I am unsure of how to proceed. Can I take $f_0=1$, since $deg(f_0)=0$, then continue in the same pattern? Also, I still don't understand why this proves the basis; I thought that it must be proved each term is *not* a linear combination of the preceding terms.

Comment: Also, I have found that $f_k=f_{k-1}+f_0t^k$ for all $k\leq{n}$. Is this true, and if so, how does this prove linear independence?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how to progress with this proof.

Comment: A basis can be defined as either a maximal linearly independent system or a *minimal generating system*, both must consist of $n+1$ elements (the dimension).

Answer (score 0):

Since that vector space has dimension $n+1$ and the given sequence has the right lenght it's enough to prove that $B$ is linearly independent. You can do this inductively: Suppose $a_0f_0+...+a_nf_n=0$, then you get $a_n=0$, then $a_{n-1}=0$ and so forth.